# Extending the scrolling area in a ScrollView / WebView / ListView

Tags: android, listview, webview, scroll, scrollview

I'm trying to create a custom scrolling component (`ScrollView`, `ListView`, `WebView`) that its scrolling area (content area) can be programmatically extended beyond the content. Add "content padding" at the bottom if you will.

I don't think that adding empty views and layouts is a good approach since it seems a little too "hackey" and forces restraints on the order of insertions.

I know that in Objective C, when programming for iOS there is direct access to the `contentSize`, in a `ScrollView` and I'm looking for (or to create) something similar. Meaning I think it would be best to affect the calculation of the content area size directly, but I'm not sure where to start.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *but I'm not sure where to start* - Start by reviewing the source code of the widgets you target and see how they do the measurements to insert your own logic. If I were you I would go with inserting some dummy view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously The source code is the first place I went, but all of these components are thousands of lines of implementation. Plus I understood that there are too many potential points of failure going that route, so I decided to go the route of adding a view that I control at the end of each container.

For the `ListView` I created a custom `ListAdapter` using the composition style, overriding the methods I needed to add my custom view as the last view in any adapter that is set in the list.

For the `ScrollView` I created a hidden layout hierarchy inside the `ScrollView`, overriding the view insertion methods to insert all views into my controlled layout, underneath which is my padding view.

For the `WebView`, since I'm not expecting any horizontal scrolling in this project, I'm sticking with wrapping it with my custom `ScrollView`.

If anyone wants more details you can leave a comment.